# JDO GAE One-to-Many problem

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, jdo

Hi i am having some problems retreiving data from the datastore...

I have a few circuses, who has some amount of attractions.

Circus:

```
@PersistenceCapable(identityType = IdentityType.APPLICATION) 
public class Circus implements Serializable
{
    @PrimaryKey  
    @Persistent(valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.IDENTITY)  
    @Extension(vendorName = "datanucleus", key = "gae.encoded-pk", value = "true")  
    private String key;
    @Persistent
    private String name;
    @Persistent(mappedBy = "owningCircus")
    @Element(dependent = "true")
    public List<Attractions> attractions;

    public Circus()
    {

    }

    public Circus(String name)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.attractions = new ArrayList<Attractions>();
    }
    public void addAttraction(Attraction attr)
    {
            this.attractions.add(attr);
    }
    // Get/Set
}
```

Attraction:

```
@PersistenceCapable(identityType = IdentityType.APPLICATION) 
public class Attraction implements Serializable
{
    @PrimaryKey
    @Persistent(valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.IDENTITY)
    @Extension(vendorName = "datanucleus", key = "gae.encoded-pk", value = "true")
    private String key;
    @Persistent
    private String name;
    @Persistent 
    private Circus owningCircus;

    //...

    public Attraction()
    {

    }

    public Attraction(Circus owning, String name)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.owningCircus = owning;
    }
    // Get/Set
}
```

This is how i get the circuses

```
public List<Circus> getCircuses()
    {
        PersistenceManager pm = PMF.get().getPersistenceManager();
        Query query = pm.newQuery("select from " + Circus.class.getName()); 
        List<Circus> circuses = (List<Circus>) query.execute();

        for(Circus c : circuses)
        {
            //Poke the list of attractions so they are loaded.
            //however, c.attractions==null => NullPointerException
            c.attractions.size();
        } 

        List<Circus> ret = (List<Circus>) pm.detachCopyAll(circuses);       

        pm.close();

        return ret;
    }
```

Circus is persisted like this

```
public void addCircus(Circus circus)
    {
        PersistenceManager pm = PMF.get().getPersistenceManager();
        pm.makePersistent(circus);
        pm.close();
    }
//...
Circus a =new Circus("Super Circus");
a.addAttraction(new Attraction(a,"George the clown"));
addCircus(a);
```

c.attractions is null for some reason..
If i look into the Data Viewer there are both circuses and attractions.. :s

Thanks

**EDIT:**
Added how the circus is persisted, aswell as owningCircus.

**EDIT 2**

I am actually getting this exception:

```
com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DatastoreNeedIndexException: no matching index found..      <datastore-index kind="Attraction" ancestor="true" source="manual">
        <property name="attractions_INTEGER_IDX" direction="asc"/>
```

Comment: Will you please show the code that sets the `attractions` list?  The code you've shown us never creates a new `List<Attraction>`.  If you haven't set the field, it will be returned as null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding a datastore-indexes.xml containing

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <datastore-indexes   autoGenerate="true"> 
<datastore-index kind="Attraction" ancestor="true" source="manual">
        <property name="attractions_INTEGER_IDX" direction="asc"/>
    </datastore-index>
</datastore-indexes>
```

to war/WEB-INF/ solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

In JDO over GAE, typed references imply an owned relationship. So to make it work try adding

```
@Persistent(mappedBy="owningCircus")
```

to **Circus** and to **Attraction** add the field

```
@Persistent private Circus owningCircus;
```

This way when creating a new attraction, setting the Circus will implicitly map the relationship. (see "entity groups" in the link below)

If you do not want an owned relationship, simply hold a list of Keys.
More on this at http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/jdo/relationships.html

Comment: When i look in the data viewer i cant actually see the owningCircus-attribute of the Attraction, nor the attractions.. However they are marked as persistent in the code.. are they supposed to show up there? Im guessing they are.